# Kolmogorov-Smirnov test with PDFs instead of data points?

Tags: joint-distribution, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, anderson-darling-test

I don't have a background in statistics, so I don't know exactly how to phrase my question, and I am likely misusing some of the statistic lingo.

I have a model which I am fitting to 30 sets of data, constructing 30 different models. To figure out the parameters for my model, I perform a Monte Carlo Markov Chain (MCMC) simulation on each data set, giving me a distribution of possible parameter values for each model. Once I've run the MCMC on all 30 data sets, I now have 30 PDFs of each of the parameters in my model. I am trying to test whether or not one of the parameters comes from a uniform parent distribution. The scientific background for my data suggests that this parameter should be drawn from a uniform distribution.

I believe this would be straightforward if I had single value measurements for each of my parameter values, just a list of 30 values of this parameter. I could then perform a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test and determine if my 30 data points are inconsistent with being drawn from a uniform distribution. And I could construct these 30 single data points by taking, say, the median of each of the 30 PDFs. However, I feel this method is overly simplistic and throws out a ton of information contained in each of the 30 PDFs.

So my question: How can I use my 30 PDFs to test whether this parameter is drawn from a uniform distribution?

One thought: Can I simply add my PDFs together and test how close the combined distribution is to uniform? If so, how could I test for "closeness".